# Grails customised message not working

Tags: grails, error-handling

Github source code https://github.com/grails-samples/grails-petclinic

Customised message has been specified, unfortunately it doesn't work.

owner.firstName.blank=You must specify a first name

It shows error message "Property [firstName] of class [class org.grails.samples.Owner] cannot be null" instead of "You must specify a first name".

I have found the same issue in this screencast http://grails.org/screencast/22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are running into is that you aren't customizing the correct message code. If you read closely you will see it's violating the `nullable` constraint not the `blank` constraint.

You should use:

```
owner.firstName.nullable=You must specify a first name
```

This may be confusing because in recent versions of Grails the default behavior for handling blank values for `String`s was changed to use `null` instead of blank. There is a configuration option available to control this in `Config.groovy` if you wish to change back to the old behavior.

Comment: That's confusing in recent versions of Grails. Thank you so much, you saved me plenty of time.  By the way, is there any document list down all the default options?